# putting a color hover on my css triangle arrow and container

Tags: css

I would like to change the color on hover, but it is not working for me, what is the reason?

*The baloon:*

```
#footer .lv2 > li > a {
*and the triangle arrow:*
#footer .lv2 > li > a:after {


  /** Drop-up menu language flag WPML **/

#footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}


#footer .lv1 > li > a {
     color: black;
     display: block;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

#footer .lv2 > li > a {
      background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
      color: black;
      display: block;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 21.8px;
      border:1px solid rgba(176,176,176,0.7);
      padding-left:  10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
 }


    }


    /* triangle arrow */

    #footer .lv2 > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
      left: 13px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px; 
        background: rgba(250,250,250, 1);
        border-right:1px solid rgba(176,176,176,0.7);
        border-bottom:1px solid rgba(176,176,176,0.7);
     -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    }

    /* no separator on last list item */
    #footer .lv1 li:last-child { background: 0; }


    #footer ul {
            list-style-type:        none;
            padding:                0;
    }

    #footer ul.lv1 {
            height:                 100%;
            margin-left:            2.5%;
            margin-right:           2.5%;
            margin-top:             0;
            z-index:                2;
    }

    #footer ul.lv2 {
            display:                none;
            z-index:                3;
    }

    /* fix margin for first drop-up menu */
    #footer li:first-child > ul.lv2 { margin-left: 0px !important; }

    #footer li:hover > ul.lv2 {
                bottom:                 26px;
                display:                block;
                position:               absolute;
                padding-bottom:         10px;

                /* align drop-up edge with separator line */
                margin-left:            -1px;

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Some HTML would be nice but I would say you could probably just add background: rgba(250,250,250, 1) to your hover style and change the rgb values to what you want, setup a jsfiddle and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for styling when something is hovered over you use the Pseudo class `:hover`, like this:

```
#footer:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

This will change the background color when the element with the `footer` ID is hovered over.

Comment: Just typed in the css: #footer {
    bottom:                 0px;
    
   display: inline-block;
 
}

#footer:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}

Comment: Right, but I noticed that you already have a rule for `:hover`, but there is no background-color property in it. What happens if you comment out the one I suggested and put the color in there?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to color the classes apart but I just get one to work and not both together....

I tried:

```
#footer .lv2 > li > a:hover:after, .lv2 > li > a:hover {
    background-color: tomato;
    }
```

and:

```
#footer .lv2 > li > a:hover:after, #footer .lv2 > li > a:hover {
    background-color: tomato;
    }
```

and:

```
 #footer .lv2 > li > a:hover:after
    background-color: tomato;
    }
 #footer .lv2 > li > a:hover
    background-color: tomato;
    }
```

any other suggestions to let it work?